# React Router and authentication contexts

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React App that utilizes firebase to handle its authentication. Currently, im using `firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);` to get whether or not the user is logged in and passing that into a context for my other components to access them. Below is my code for the AuthContext and AuthProvider

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
      firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
  },[]);
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value = {{currentUser}}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

This Auth Provider is used to encapsulate my router so that all routes have access to the Auth Context

```
<AuthProvider>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <LoggedRoute exact path = "/" component = {Home}/>
            <Route exact path = "/login" component = {Login}/>
            <Route exact path = "/groups/:id" component = {GroupDash}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</AuthProvider>
```

However, in my GroupDash component, I can't access the AuthContext if I directly try and go to ".../groups/groupID", but I can access it if I use `history.push("/groups/${groupID}")` from another page that does have the AuthContext. Because of this, I always get an error since currentUser is null. Is there any reason for the context to not pass in? I'm definitely logged in.

```
const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

useEffect(() =>{
    groupRef.get().then(snapshot =>{
        const groupData = snapshot.data()
        const uids = []
        groupData.groupMembers.forEach(member =>{
            uids.push(member.uid)
        })
        permitted.current = uids.includes(currentUser.uid)

    })
}, [currentUser.uid, groupRef])
```

Comment: I guess the [other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078976/react-authentication-context-being-null-initially) is linked with this and the solution to it, solved this problem too

Comment: Yes, the other question is linked to this, and I might close this question soon.